# Check this function is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $S=[0,1)$ and $d$ be a function defined by
\begin{align*}
d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
|x-y|, \quad\text{if} \,\,0\leq|x-y|<\frac{1}{2},\\
1-|x-y|,\quad\text{if}\,\,\frac{1}{2}\leq |x-y|<1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*} for all $x,y\in S$.

I want to check whether $d$ is a metric on $S$. But, for the case $\frac{1}{2}\leq |x-y|<1$,  I can not show that $d$ satisfies the axiom $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$. So, I think it is not a metric.
Maybe everyone here can tell me, is it correct that $d$ is not metric?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If $\frac{1}{2}\leq |x-y|<1$ then $d(x, y) = 1-|x-y| > 0$.

Comment: If $x=y$ then the case $1/2\le |x-y|<1$ is never valid so you don't need to prove it for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i)

If $x=y$ then it is clear that $d(x,y)=0$

(ii)

Let $d(x,y)=0$

Now, if $0\leq|x-y|<\frac{1}{2}$ then $|x-y|=0$ and thus $x=y$

If  $\frac{1}{2}\leq|x-y|<1$ then $1-|x-y|=0$. This implies that $|x-y|=1$ but this is not possible for given set $S$.

Thus if $d(x,y)=0$ then $\frac{1}{2}\leq|x-y|<1$ is not possible and hence, $d(x,y)=0$ $\implies$ $x=y$.